# How to list files, located on media server?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, red5, flash-media-server

How to list streams, already recorded or saved on media server? Can you point me some examples? Do you know where are the sources of `ofla_demo.swf` is located?

**P.S.**

I need to list files being on client side.

Answer (score 0):

The oflaDemo code for the server displays how to list the files and provide them to a client. The server project source may be found here: http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/example/trunk/oflaDemo/

View this java file to see how the filter and listing is created:
http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/java/example/trunk/oflaDemo/src/org/red5/demos/oflaDemo/DemoService.java

The source for the oflaDemo client is in AS2 format (.fla) and is located here: http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/flash/trunk/ofla_demo.fla